# django: pass a model to a form

Tags: django, forms, parameters, model

I'd like to pass a model "modelToUse" to my form:

```
class ActsAddForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.modelToUse = kwargs.pop('modelToUse')
        super(ActsAddForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    actsToValidate=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=modelToUse.objects.filter(validated=0), empty_label="Select an act to validate", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))
```

I've got the error "name 'modelToUse' is not defined". What's wrong?

I want to call it in my view:

```
addForm=ActsAddForm(modelToUse=ActsIdsModel())
```

Comment: Why not use a `ModelForm`?

Comment: There is only one field in this form, a drop down list. So I don't need to use a model, so no need to use a ModelForm.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the way scope and classes work in Python. `actsToValidate` is a class-level property, and will be evaluated when the class is *defined*. `__init__`, on the other hand, is evaluated when the class is *instantiated*.

And even if they were evaluated in the right order, it still wouldn't work, because you haven't put `modelToUse` into the class scope, where it can be seen by the field definition.

You need to define the field at the class level without the queryset, then add it in the `__init__` method. Like this:

```
class ActsAddForm(forms.Form):
    actsToValidate=forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="Select an act to validate", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        modelToUse = kwargs.pop('modelToUse')
        super(ActsAddForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['actsToValidate'].queryset=modelToUse.objects.filter(validated=0)
```

Comment: I think I can't declare a ModelChoiceField without queryset, cause now I get the error "__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)" at the declaration of actsToValidate.

Comment: OK, so choose one of your models to be the default.

Comment: I get this error now: "global name 'modelToUse' is not defined" (at the last line).

Comment: Sorry, I had an extra `self` in there. Try it now.

Comment: Now I get a KeyError: 'modelToUse'. File "/var/www/europolix/actsIdsValidation/views.py" in actsView
  230.   responseDic['addForm'] = ActsAddForm(modelToUse=ActsAddForm())
File "/var/www/europolix/actsIdsValidation/forms.py" in __init__
  114.         modelToUse = kwargs.pop('modelToUse')

Exception Type: KeyError at /actsIdsValidation/index.html
Exception Value: 'modelToUse'